# Lag in Activity/fragment due to recyclerView

Tags: java, android

Lag in loading activity/fragment when the recyclerView is visible in fragment/activity. If the activity is not show (visibility:gone) the recyclerview the lag gone...

```
private void setRecentHisRecycler(List<OrderList> popularAdsList) {

    ordersAdapter = new OrdersAdapter(getContext(), sagaPopularAdsList, getActivity());
    binding.orderHisRecentRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    binding.orderHisRecentRecycler.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    binding.orderHisRecentRecycler.setScrollContainer(false);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
    binding.orderHisRecentRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    binding.orderHisRecentRecycler.setAdapter(ordersAdapter);


}
```

no Problem with this code..

```
    profileViewModel.getRecentOrderItem().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), orderLists1 -> {


        orderLists.clear();
        orderLists.addAll(orderLists1);
        ordersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        binding.perviousOrderLayout.setVisibility(orderLists.size() <= 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
       

    });
```

when I set recuclerView ConstraingLayout Visiblity to visible the fragment loading time increase 300ms to 2 seconds..

if I past the

binding.perviousOrderLayout.setVisibility(orderLists.size() <= 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);

in start of the observer the lag gone but the data not visible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.ProfileFragment">
       <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
          <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
               <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/profileToolbarLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView26"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/bitter_bold"
                    android:text="My Account"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/perviousOrderLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/yourOrdersTv">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/orderHisRecentRecycler"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                    tools:itemCount="1"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/orders_list" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            
            
                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: probably due to your data loading scheme, check if you are loading the recyclerview data on the main thread

Comment: Please add your code for your recyclerview and adapter. There's no way for anyone to help if they can't see your code.

Comment: i am using firebase to get data and using viewModel..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this... Use Multi view RecyclerView instead of nestedScrollView